# Getting Bounding Area for Quadkeys

Tags: java, latitude-longitude, spatial

I have a bunch of quadkeys and would like to get the bounding box coordinates that is an extent of all of them i.e. the min/max lat and long that would contain all the quadkeys. Is there a library that would help get this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadkeys are just another way of displaying X/Y/Zoom coordinates of a MapTile system.

Lets assume your quadkeys are all the same resolution (Zoom level), i.e. they all have the same number of digits.

If you convert the quadkey's back to X/Y coordinates, then it becomes a simple geometry problem: Find the X,Y coordinates for top-left, and bottom-right of a box that contains a series of X,Y points. Let me know if you need help with that, though it should be basic Euclidean Geometry.

Once you find those two corner points, convert them back to Lat/Long, and you will have the Lat/Long points of a bounding box that contains your Quadkeys.

[MSDN has example source code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) showing the conversions between Lat/Long, X/Y/Zoom and QuadKeys.